# jqGrid - URL from custom button works only for the first time

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I got a grid with a custom button. If the user clicks this button, I call an URL sending a code (that I get from the selected row) and another grid is displayed according to the code. The problem is that it just works for the first time I click on the button.. if I close the window (with the 2nd grid) and try to select another row and click on the button again, it opens the grid with the URL set before (I looked on Firebug and it doesn't call the URL, it looks like it's static or something like that). Here is my code:

grid1

```
onClickButton: function(){ 
    var dados = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
    var codigo = $("#grid").jqGrid('getCell', dados, 'codigo');
    if(dados){
        abreDialogUsuario(); //opens dialog
        mostraGridGruposUsuario(codigo); //shows grid on dialog passing the code by parameter               
    } 
}
```

grid2

```
function mostraGridGruposUsuario(codUsuario){ //gets the code
    alert(codUsuario);
    $("#grid_gruposUsuario").jqGrid({   
        datatype: 'json',
        url: 'teste.jsp?codUsuario='+codUsuario,
                ...
                ...
    }
}
```

NOTE: the alert shows the correct codUsuario (regardless the code from selected row) but for some reason it doesn't call URL with the code.

Comment: Is it opening the dialog the second time?

Comment: It opens the dialog but not with the correct data. If in the first time I select the row 3 for example and then close it and select the row 7, the dialog shows the data from the row 3

Comment: Instead of reloading the grid, have you considered just updating the url or postData param with setGridParam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to recreate jqGrid with new URL you first need to unload the old one, change your code like this:

```
function mostraGridGruposUsuario(codUsuario) {
   alert(codUsuario);

   $('#grid_gruposUsuario').jqGrid('GridUnload');
   $("#grid_gruposUsuario").jqGrid({   
       datatype: 'json',
       url: 'teste.jsp?codUsuario=' + codUsuario,
       ...
   }
}
```

As an alternative you can create the grid only once (for example in dialog initialization function) and only change the URL before displaying the grid:

```
$("#grid_gruposUsuario").jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: 'teste.jsp?codUsuario=' + codUsuario }).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Just choose the scenario which better suits you.

Comment: Thanks! I tried with the .jqGrid('GridUnload') and it worked :)